# How to set state for a specific object in an array in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, state

I have list of Map in my state in my React app. Ex:

```
item : [ { name: 'abc', age: '10' }, { name: 'xyz', age: '2' }, { name: 'sdf', age: '6'} ]
```

How would I update the state, if I want to just change set 'age': 10 for   name 'xjz'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs

Comment: What have you tried? One way you can do it is using [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) with the condition you need to match and then update the object at that `index`. Also, name `xjz` is not available on your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to `map` your array and only replace the item where your condition matches :

```
this.setState(prev => ({
    item: prev.item.map(item => item.name === 'xjz' ? { ...item, age: '10' } : item)
}))
```

In a class function :

```
changeValue = name => {
    this.setState(prev => ({
        item: prev.item.map(item => item.name === name ? { ...item, age: '10' } : item)
    }))
}

changeValue('xyz')
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  You solution worked perfect !!!

Comment: Glad it helped, feel free to accept it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new array mapping to old one with new values:

```js
const initial = [
  { name: 'abc', age: '10' },
  { name: 'xyz', age: '2' },
  { name: 'sdf', age: '6'}
]

const updated = initial.map(element =>
                  element.name === 'xyz'
                    ? { ...element, age: 10 }
                    : element
                )
                
console.log(updated)
/*
[
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "age": "10"
  },
  {
    "name": "xyz",
    "age": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "sdf",
    "age": "6"
  }
]
*/
```

Remember that if you need the previous state to compute the next one, you need to call setState passing a function that takes the previous state as the first argument:

```
this.setState(
  prevState => ({
    // ... the new state here (where you map over your items)
  })
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use map. for example:

```
const newData = data.map(val => {
  if(val.id === id) {
    return {...val, name: 'new name'};
  }
  return val;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You would have to update the associated variable in the state:

```
this.state.values[1].age = 10;

this.setState({
    values,
});
```